# Allow specific GitHub user to clone a private repository

Tags: git, github

I need to allow one Github account (lets call this account A) to clone some private repository of another account. A is a machine user, there is actually no human to lead it.

Of course, the private repository's owner want to share it with A (but only with A).

The first thing I tried to do is by using a SSH key but I didn't succeed. If I'm not wrong, there is no way to clone a private repository if you're not either the owner, or a collaborator. (If it's actually possible, I really want to know how).

Then, I tried to do the next thing: the repository's owner should add the A as collaborator. Then, A has to accept the request and it will be possible to clone. The question is since A is a machine user, there isn't any way to accept a request with a Git command. Another solution would be to accept every collaborator request automatically.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm going to recommend a different approach. It sounds like a [deploy key](https://developer.github.com/v3/guides/managing-deploy-keys/#deploy-keys) might solve your problem. This completely bypasses the need for machine user A to have a GitHub account.

1. Generate an SSH key for machine user A
2. Go to your repository's settings page in GitHub's web UI
3. In the sidebar, click Deploy Keys and then Add Deploy Key
4. Paste the generated public key and provide a title for it, then click Add Key

Each deploy key can only be used with a single repository. By default, deploy keys grant read-only access.